# How do I using multiple gmail accounts with gmail API on the python project?

Tags: python, json, api, gmail-api

I trying create a project using few gmail accounts. I added first gmail account and its working clearly but I am stuck when I trying add other accounts. I check on Google doc. and i dont find. A credentials.json file was generated when I added the first account and only one credentials file was generated for a project as far as I know. So, How do I using other gmail accounts's data in my project?

**Here is my code:**

```
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

def gmail_authenticate():
creds = None

if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
    with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)
return build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

service = gmail_authenticate()



get_email = service.users().messages().list(userId="example@gmail.com",labelIds= ["UNREAD"]).execute()
```

**here is my project directory:**

```
-credentials.json
-gmailAPI.py
-token.json
-token.pickle
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `but I am stuck when I trying add other accounts.`?

Comment: Of course. I want get unread headers of my gmail accounts. and to be honest, I dont know how do I using other accounts to same projecct because I am begginer in using API.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, if you want to use Gmail API with 2 accounts, it is required to authorize for each account. So in your script, it is required to retrieve the files of `credentials.json` for each account. Although I'm not sure about your actual goal, if you want to achieve this using one script, how about looping your script using the files of `credentials.json` of 2 accounts?

Comment: Let me explain to my goal. I want create a trading bot. And I use 2 account for this. first gmail for the Long position. and second gmail for the Short position.  And I want check this mails for when system sent Long and Short signal and then my algorithim open the position automaticly but I dont know to when system send this message. Therefore, I want  my algorithm working continually.  you explained to "FOR LOOP".  I would be very happy if you are coding to your explain in the answer area.

Answer (score 0):

### Service account

You can get the unread headers of your Gmail accounts by using a service account and [impersonate](https://medium.com/google-cloud/impersonating-users-with-google-cloud-platform-service-accounts-ba762db09092) any user within your domain. But I'm assuming you're using free Gmail accounts, and that won't be feasible.

### OAuth token

You need to authorize all the Gmail accounts you have in your script by getting an [OAuth token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingcred). So your app will have the permissions to access your accounts' data

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow

# Use the client_secret.json file to identify the application requesting
# authorization. The client ID (from that file) and access scopes are required.
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'])

# Indicate where the API server will redirect the user after the user completes
# the authorization flow. The redirect URI is required. The value must exactly
# match one of the authorized redirect URIs for the OAuth 2.0 client, which you
# configured in the API Console. If this value doesn't match an authorized URI,
# you will get a 'redirect_uri_mismatch' error.
flow.redirect_uri = 'https://www.example.com/oauth2callback'

# Generate URL for request to Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
# Use kwargs to set optional request parameters.
authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
    # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
    # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
    access_type='offline',
    # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
    include_granted_scopes='true')
```

After the function runs, you will be prompted to login with your Gmail account and accept all the permissions you request.